# Disable unathorized access log warning

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Our ASP.NET Core MVC app adds a warning entry to the log each time a user who is not authenticated tries to access a resource:

```
Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
```

This is happens whenever a user's auth session times out, so the behaviour is expected.

Is there anyway to prevent MVC from logging this event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't disable particular warning, but you can enable logging for this class with level `Error` or above.

Add to `appsettings.json`:

```
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization": "Error"  <-- logger classname and minimum log level
    }
  }
```

Add to `Startup.Configure(...)`:

```
loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
```

It's up to you how many log outputs you have (Console, Db, etc) - important that you configure it from configuration, where different loggers have different log levels.